# Read 100MB of a 1.5 GB log file and create Solr index

Tags: solr, indexing, large-files

My requirement is - I have a huge log file maybe 1GB or 1.5GB. I want to read 100MB chunks and create Solr index on the chunk or if possible create custom index.

Loading the whole file might create a heap space issue and I do not want to use `BufferedReader.readline()` to create custom index.

Is there any recommendation on the approach I should take.

Comment: Why not use `readline`? If it is because the information is spread over several lines, you might gather the information in a buffer. Would you give a small sample of the file content?